# Swift 4 UIDatePicker position to the bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I have using `UIDatePicker`, I am wondering whats the best way to get in the same position as `UIPickerView` (the `UIPickerView` is always at the bottom) my `UIDatePicker` position if full width, but not at the bottom, if I remove the frame setting, it goes to the top left, not full width:

```
let datePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200)
datePicker.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GradingController.datePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
self.view.addSubview(datePicker)
```

Comment: maybe you should add some constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add it as textInputView in textField then you will not need to set frame but if you want to add it on view then you have to set frame and you need to manage Y position, set your frame like this:

```
 datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 200, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200)
```

Or

```
 datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - 200, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200)
```